# Basic error - how to fix?

Tags: android

I just started programming in Android Studio, and I just happend to get an error which says: "Cannot resolve symbol 'R'", I looked it up on google and Stack Overflow and couldn't find a solution that fixes my problem. 
I've seen so many things saying i need to import stuff or clean and build, but when i try it - it doesn't help me, would be helpful if someone could explain this to me cause perhaps im doing something wrong trying to fix it ...

This is my code:

.Java file:

```
package com.example.android.courtcounter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int scoreA=0,scoreB=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void displayForTeamA(int score) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_score);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }
    public void displayForTeamB(int score) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_b_score);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }
    public void addThreeForTeamA(View v)
    {
        scoreA+=3;
        displayForTeamA(scoreA);
    }
    public void addTwoForTeamA(View v)
    {
        scoreA+=2;
        displayForTeamA(scoreA);
    }
    public void addOneForTeamA(View v)
    {
        scoreA+=1;
        displayForTeamA(scoreA);
    }

    public void addThreeForTeamB(View v)
    {
        scoreB+=3;
        displayForTeamB(scoreB);
    }
    public void addTwoForTeamB(View v)
    {
        scoreB+=2;
        displayForTeamB(scoreB);
    }
    public void addOneForTeamB(View v)
    {
        scoreB+=1;
        displayForTeamB(scoreB);
    }
    public void setToZero(View v)
    {
        scoreA=0;
        scoreB=0;
        displayForTeamA(scoreA);
        displayForTeamB(scoreB);
    }
}
```

.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">



            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Team A"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="#616161"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="56dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+3 Points"
                android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
                android:onClick="addThreeForTeamA"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+2 Points"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:onClick="addTwoForTeamA"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Free Throw"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:onClick="addOneForTeamA"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"/>



        </LinearLayout>

        <view
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">


        </view>



        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">



            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Team B"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="#616161"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="56dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+3 Points"
                android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
                android:onClick="addThreeForTeamB"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+2 Points"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:onClick="addTwoForTeamB"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Free Throw"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:onClick="addOneForTeamB"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"/>



        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reset"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="setToZero"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be appriciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean your project. That might help if it doesn't close the project and delete the .gradle and reopen the project

Comment: TextView scoreView;   //this should be global               scoreView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.team_b_score); // this should be in your oncreate. Do Same for the rest

Comment: still doesn't work. im getting these compilation errors like: failed linking file resources or: "error: resource string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior (aka com.example.android.courtcounter:string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior) not found. "
and error: resource string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior (aka com.example.android.courtcounter:string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior) not found. 


These are my errors and i still get that Cannot resovle 'R' symbol.

Comment: I copied the code on to another project and it worked, might have been something in the manifest i played with

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error is caused by Gradle version incompatibility. Update your gradle version by hovering over the current version and clicking update. Then clean and rebuild your project. That should do it.